# Get current desktop wallpaper in ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, ctypes

I try to get path to current wallpaper in Python using ctypes module. But as a result program returns value 1.

```
import ctypes

SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0073

path = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(260)
a = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, 100, path, 0)
print(a)
```

Comment: This information is exposed through the [`IDesktopWallpaper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper) interface starting with Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is returned in `path`.  `a` in your example is the return code (1=success).  It's also a good habit to define the argument types and return type so `ctypes` doesn't have to guess when converting parameters from Python to C and vice versa.

```py
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0073

dll = ct.WinDLL('user32')
dll.SystemParametersInfoW.argtypes = w.UINT,w.UINT,w.LPVOID,w.UINT
dll.SystemParametersInfoW.restype = w.BOOL

path = ct.create_unicode_buffer(260)
result = dll.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, ct.sizeof(path), path, 0)
print(result, path.value)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you advice a website where I can find necessary docuentation about ctypes module and how to work with memory and buffer allocation?

Comment: @ghfnc703 The [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) documentation.  [Fundamental Datatypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) discusses using `create_unicode_buffer()` and has examples using `.value`.

Comment: Alright, thanks again. I appreciate your assistance

Answer (score -1):

Try this code if you want, maybe it will help you :)

```
from os import path, getenv, getcwd
from ctypes import windll
import ctypes
from shutil import copyfile
from PIL import Image
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0073

path = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(260)
returnImgObj = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, 100, path, 0)

currentWallpaper = getenv(
            'APPDATA') + "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Themes\\TranscodedWallpaper"   #this is path manuel 

if returnImgObj == True:
        
        a= Image.open(currentWallpaper)
        a.show()
        print(str(currentWallpaper))
        
else:
        tempFile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode="wb", suffix='.jpg').name
        copyfile(currentWallpaper, tempFile)
        a= Image.open(currentWallpaper)
        a.show()
        print(str(currentWallpaper))
```

Comment: A quality answer needs to include the following: `1` An explanation what the issue is. `2` How the proposed solution addresses the issue. *"Try this code"* type of answers aren't generally useful.

Comment: @Muhammet Ali Kayacan The problem is that I want to get desktop wallpaper exactly via ctypes module. I already know how to do that with pywin32, but I'd prefer to use ctypes